# Invalid alias verb (for /f)

Tags: for-loop, batch-file, cmd

I am learning to code the BATCH,
I would like to make a small .bat executable to retrieve various information on computers that I reinstall, to avoid having to navigate through several sections of the windows control panel.

I have already managed to retrieve some information using "for /f", but I must admit that I still don't understand how this command works.

I haven't found any more info on what I'm looking for, so I'm asking for help which would be very welcome.

I'm not looking for a copy/paste solution, I'd like someone to explain my mistake and help me solve it so I can better understand where I went wrong.

Anyway, after reading this indigestible pamphlet, here are the commands I'm looking to run:

```
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%I in (
    'wmic LOGICALDISK where DriveType!=4 get DeviceID /value'
) do for /f "delims=" %%# in ("%%I") do set "deviceid=%%~#"


for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%I in (
    'wmic LOGICALDISK where drivetype!=4 get description /value'
) do for /f "delims=" %%# in ("%%I") do set "description=%%~#"


for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%I in (
    'wmic LOGICALDISK where drivetype!=4 get volumename /value'
) do for /f "delims=" %%# in ("%%I") do set "volumename=%%~#"


for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%I in (
    'wmic LOGICALDISK where drivetype!=4 get Size /value'
) do for /f "delims=" %%# in ("%%I") do set "Size=%%~#"
```

and this is what I get back:

```
C:\Users\rv\Desktop>for /F "tokens=2 delims==" %I in ('wmic LOGICALDISK where DriveType! 4 get DeviceID /value') do for /F "delims=" %# in ("%I") do set "deviceid=%~#"
4 - Verbe de l'alias non valide.

C:\Users\rv\Desktop>for /F "tokens=2 delims==" %I in ('wmic LOGICALDISK where drivetype! 4 get description /value') do for /F "delims=" %# in ("%I") do set "description=%~#"
4 - Verbe de l'alias non valide.

C:\Users\rv\Desktop>for /F "tokens=2 delims==" %I in ('wmic LOGICALDISK where drivetype! 4 get volumename /value') do for /F "delims=" %# in ("%I") do set "volumename=%~#"
4 - Verbe de l'alias non valide.

C:\Users\rv\Desktop>for /F "tokens=2 delims==" %I in ('wmic LOGICALDISK where drivetype! 4 get Size /value') do for /F "delims=" %# in ("%I") do set "Size=%~#"
4 - Verbe de l'alias non valide.
```

I think this is due to a misuse of "tokens=" and "delims=" on my part ?

Comment: Start with ```"drivetype != 4"```. Then please consider using `Get Description^, DeviceID^, Size^, VolumeName`, so that everything is returned from one command instyead of four.

Comment: You need `...!^=4...` - The caret is necessary to escape the `=` to turn off its special meaning. Also `%%#~ is not officially supported; there are plenty of supported symbols (all alphabetical caracters in both cases = 52)

Comment: Please also be aware that there will likely be more than one drive not reported with a DriveType of `4`, (i.e. non network drives). This means that each of your resulting variables will only hold the string value for the last result returned for each property!

Comment: Alternative to escaping each poison char individually, you can make the whole command save by quoting it: `for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%I in ('"wmic LOGICALDISK where drivetype!=4 get description /value"') do ...` (may be difficult/unintuitive when the command itself contains quotes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[How-to: Escape Characters, Delimiters and Quotes at the Windows command line.](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html)

In Windows cmd/batch scripting, parameters are most often separated by spaces, but any of the following are also valid delimiters:

- `,` (U+002C,  *Comma*)
- `;` (U+003B,  *Semicolon*)
- `=` (U+003D,  *Equals Sign*)
- (U+0020,  *Space*)
- `␉` (U+0009,  *Character Tabulation*)

You need to *escape* the *Equals Sign* in `DriveType!=4`. Use any of the following:

- `"DriveType!=4"` (using "Double Quotes")
- `DriveType!^=4` (using common escape character  `^` (U+005E,  *Circumflex Accent*))

Answer (score 1):

Mmm... I used to think/solve this type of problems in "opposite order"... Please, follow me.

I started typing this command at the command-prompt:

```
C:\> wmic LOGICALDISK where DriveType!=4 get DeviceID /value


DeviceID=C:


DeviceID=D:
```

Ok. I always try to make things in an efficient way. If I can get the same result from a single command instead of 4 commands, then I always opted for the single one:

```
C:\> wmic LOGICALDISK where DriveType!=4 get DeviceID,Description,VolumeName,Size /value


Description=Local Fixed Disk
DeviceID=C:
Size=982768414720
VolumeName=Windows


Description=Local Fixed Disk
DeviceID=D:
Size=16111366144
VolumeName=RECOVERY
```

Good! In order to "get" such values, we need to execute the `wmic` command from a `for /F` command, so I wrote this simple Batch file at first:

```
for /F "delims=" %%a in ('wmic LOGICALDISK where DriveType!=4 get DeviceID,Description,VolumeName,Size /value') do @echo [%%a]
```

... and the problems started:

```
C:\> for /F "delims=" %a in ('wmic LOGICALDISK where DriveType! 4 get DeviceID Description VolumeName Size /value') do @echo [%a]
4 - Verbo de alias no válido.
```

If you compare the source line vs. the executed command, you'll realize that the equal-sign and the commas disappeared! This happens because these characters: **`= , ;`** works as separators for items in most commands (besides space and TAB). This is this way just because MS (Microsoft) decided that...  **`:(`**

There are two ways to solve this problem: individually caret-^escape each one of these characters *OR* enclose the whole command in quotes. I choose the second method because it is simpler:

```
for /F "delims=" %%a in ('"wmic LOGICALDISK where DriveType!=4 get DeviceID,Description,VolumeName,Size /value"') do @echo [%%a]
```

And the output is:

```
C:\> for /F "delims=" %a in ('"wmic LOGICALDISK where DriveType!=4 get DeviceID,Description,VolumeName,Size /value"') do @echo [%a]
]
]
]Description=Local Fixed Disk
]DeviceID=C:
]Size=982768414720
]VolumeName=Windows
]
]
]Description=Local Fixed Disk
]DeviceID=D:
]Size=16111366144
]VolumeName=RECOVERY
]
]
]
```

So far so good, we have solved the equal-sign and comma problem... However, a *new* problem arises: the lines we think were empty really contain a CR character! There are a couple methods to solve this new point, and the one you used before is the simplest one: process the `wmic` output lines in a *second* `FOR` command:

```
for /F "delims=" %%a in (
   '"wmic LOGICALDISK where DriveType!=4 get DeviceID,Description,VolumeName,Size /value"'
) do @(
   for /F "delims=" %%b in ("%%a") do @echo [%%b]
)
```

And the output is:

```
C:\> for /F "delims=" %a in ('"wmic LOGICALDISK where DriveType!=4 get DeviceID,Description,VolumeName,Size /value"') do @(for /F "delims=" %b in ("%a") do @echo [%b]
 )
[Description=Local Fixed Disk]
[DeviceID=C:]
[Size=982768414720]
[VolumeName=Windows]
[Description=Local Fixed Disk]
[DeviceID=D:]
[Size=16111366144]
[VolumeName=RECOVERY]
```

Perfect! Now, that we are sure that the code will process the values we want, we insert an `@echo off` command at beginning and split each line in two parts, the variable and its value:

```
@echo off

for /F "delims=" %%a in (
   '"wmic LOGICALDISK where DriveType!=4 get DeviceID,Description,VolumeName,Size /value"'
) do (
   for /F "tokens=1,2 delims==" %%b in ("%%a") do echo [%%b=%%c]
)
```

The output is the same than before.

Finally, we insert code to save the value of each variable and process all variables each time that a group is complete; that is:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set "VolumeName="
for /F "delims=" %%a in (
   '"wmic LOGICALDISK where DriveType^!=4 get DeviceID,Description,VolumeName,Size /value"'
) do (
   for /F "tokens=1,2 delims==" %%b in ("%%a") do set "%%b=%%c"
   if defined VolumeName (
      echo/
      echo ===== New disk =====
      echo Description=!Description!
      echo DeviceID=!DeviceID!
      echo Size=!Size!
      echo VolumeName=!VolumeName!
      set "VolumeName="
   )
)
```

The final output:

```
===== New disk =====
Description=Local Fixed Disk
DeviceID=C:
Size=982768414720
VolumeName=Windows

===== New disk =====
Description=Local Fixed Disk
DeviceID=D:
Size=16111366144
VolumeName=RECOVERY
```

Note that in the last code the exclamation-mark needs to be ^escaped. This is because the `EnableDelayedExpansion` setlocal's option enables the **`!`** as a method to expand variables additional to the `%standard%` one. You can find a lot of questions/answers about this topic in this site...

Comment: Hello and thank you for taking the time to answer me!
It is now much clearer for me, even if I see that I still have a lot of things to study!

It works perfectly well!